# tensor1d() requires values to be a flat/TypedArray

Tags: keras, prediction, tensor, tensorflow.js, image-conversion

I am trying to predict the result after loading the my model.json file. (The model.json file is obtained after converting it from keras model by using tf.convertor). When I am passing the image in my model for the predict method I am getting the error as 17 tensors received , expecting 1. To overcome the issue I am trying to convert the image in 1d array. After doing that I am getting the error as - **tensor1d() requires values to be a flat/TypedArray.**

I using node.js and angular for frontend of the webservice.

Can somebody help?

I am attaching my modelload function -

```
async function loadModel(){

image.src = 'IM-0007-0001.jpeg'
const tensor = tf.tensor1d(image)
// console.log(tensor.shape)

const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem('atrbts/json/model.json');
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
  console.log("Model loaded")
 
  const prediction = model.predict(tensor)
}

loadModel()
```

I am expecting the result as yes or no after prediction but struggling in conversion of the image.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/?_gl=1*rimpz6*_ga*MTY5MzE1MTI2OC4xNjU5NDcwNDEx*_ga_W0YLR4190T*MTY3NjMyNjYyOS42NC4xLjE2NzYzMjY2MjkuMC4wLjA.#tensor1d), passing an image to `tf.tensor1d` isn't an option.

```
tf.tensor1d (values, dtype?) functionsource
Creates rank-1 tf.Tensor with the provided values, shape and dtype.

The same functionality can be achieved with tf.tensor(), but in general we recommend using tf.tensor1d() as it makes the code more readable.

[Example]
tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3]).print();

>> Tensor
    [1, 2, 3]

Parameters:
values (TypedArray|Array) The values of the tensor. Can be array of numbers, or a TypedArray.
dtype ('float32'|'int32'|'bool'|'complex64'|'string') The data type. Optional
Returns: tf.Tensor1D
```

It is also unlikely that a model that takes in an image would use a 1d. For example, using the [`tf.browser.fromPixels`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/?_gl=1*rimpz6*_ga*MTY5MzE1MTI2OC4xNjU5NDcwNDEx*_ga_W0YLR4190T*MTY3NjMyNjYyOS42NC4xLjE2NzYzMjY2MjkuMC4wLjA.#browser.fromPixels) function takes in image data and returns a 3d tensor.

Based on your questions that you've posted here, it seems like you could benefit from learning more of the foundations of TensorFlow.js. I recommend checking out my colleague Jason's YouTube playlist, [Machine Learning for Web Developers](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILr3HQpqjLAUkIPa5EaZiui), which is on the Google Developers YouTube channel.

Comment: Thank you for commenting and mentioning! I will definitely go through the course mentioned. I would like to ask you how to pass an image to an existing model. (I have converted the model from keras{h5 format} to json) and I am fetching the image from browser and I am expecting the result of my model after using the predict() function. Can you advise on how to proceed and pass the image so that the image is accepted by the trained model?